# Dynamic element ID in jQuery script on click event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'me trying to implement an on/off button on a php loop but I can't make it work because of the id of jQuery event. How can I get the correct id on click and pass it to the rest of the script?

The problem is in the $('#myonoffswitch')...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
          var myonoffswitch=$('#myonoffswitch').val();
          var wnfID=$('#wnfID').val();
          if ($("#myonoffswitch:checked").length == 0) {
              var a="2";
              var b=wnfID;
          } else {
              var a="3";
              var b=wnfID;
          }

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax_wnf_status.php",
              data: "statusWnf="+a+"&wnfID="+b,
              success: function(html) {
                  $("#display").html(html).show();
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

I'm generating different id's for the loop rows (ex: id="#myonoffswitch1" ; id="#myonoffswitch2"; etc).

Comment: myonoffswitch should be a class then you can get the id in the jq

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I fully understand the question, but `.val()` will not get the ID of an element. You should use `.attr('id')` instead.

Also, it looks like you're trying to format data for a GET request, not a POST.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you're looking for

```
event.target.id
```

where 'event' is passed in to your handler:

```
('#myonoffswitch').click(function(event){
    id = event.target.id
    . . .
```

Though at that point, you might not need the id, since you can just use event.target directly.